# Flask csrf: key is missing with Blueprint

Tags: flask, flask-login

Hello everyone I have this issue I am not able to correct:

KeyError: 'A secret key is required to use CSRF.'

I am now using Flask with Blueprint. 
I am not using CSRF at all but I think the LoginForm is.

I structured my project with Blueprint.
Before that, everything was find.

Here is my **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.config import Config
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate(db)
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
csrf = CSRFProtect()


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message_category = "info"

from Flask import models
from Flask.models import User

admin = Admin(name='Admin')

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    admin.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from Flask.users.routes import users
    app.register_blueprint(users)

    return app
```

This is my config.py file:

```
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = "ef2006629e09b70e55a6fb95c4e3a538"
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///site.db"
    # WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY= "bjk567nvhbvj63vg363vghvghv3768vgfbkijvr784"
    # CSRF_ENABLED = True
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `SECRET_KEY=<Your secret key here>` property in your configuration. It must be a difficult string.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply
I have already set up the secret key in my config.py file, I do not know where the problems come from

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

I was not calling properly my config.py file

In my **init**.py file I change the line:
from flask.config import Config

with the line:
from Flask.config import Config

Flask is the name of my file, which is different from flask.
I should have found another name